# How to get a list of unique tags used on a html file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Any online tool or simple vanilla Javascript that can output a list of all *unique* html tags used on a html file?

The purpose for this is that I want to reset some of the default styles, and I just want to make sure that I am targeting all of the element that I need, not leaving anyone by mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should do it :

```
let tags = []
for(tag of document.body.getElementsByTagName('*')){
  if(!tags.includes(tag.tagName))
    tags.push(tag.tagName);
}
console.log(tags)
```

Open the webpage and run that code in your console.

Comment: That is a clean, short, and perfect answer. Thanks! Works beautifully.

Comment: I hope that I am not abusing by asking for this (and sorry if that is the case), but even though the script is *exactly* what I needed, I was wondering if there is an easy way to output the list without the numbered list, in lowercase and in alphabetical order? — I am just baffle that a tool like that does not exist (or that it is so hard to find).

Comment: yes easily, just use the lower tagName, and instead of printing the list to the console, sort it first, then iterate on it and print elements one by one.